# facebook 3.5sdk open graph Explicitly Share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get my OpenGraph action to the news feed, and I learned that for that I need to add the `ExplicitlyShared` Capability to the Facebook app's OpenGraph action settings, and I did. Yet when I put it in my code, like this:

```
OpenGraphObject model = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("origame_app:model");
model.setProperty("title", modelname);
model.setProperty("url", "http://samples.ogp.me/1386546688246429");
model.setProperty("description", modeldesc);

Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(filepath[position], 500, 500);
List<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
images.add(bitmap);

OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
action.setProperty("model", model);
action.setExplicitlyShared(true);

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "origame_app:fold", "model")
    .setImageAttachmentsForObject("model", images, true)
    .build();

uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

I get an error. But otherwise the OpenGraph works great. What's the problem?

Comment: Post the error you get

Comment: Failed to generate preview for user

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? Can you share with me how to use action.setExplicitlyShared(true);

Answer (score 0):

I was also dealing with this issue and finally, I found a workaround. Instead of calling

```
action.setExplicitlyShared(true);
```

use

```
action.setProperty("explicitly_shared", true);
```

I reported this bug to Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/559486710849474/.